# How can I install perf for Linux kernel 6.1.0-060100-generic on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, perf, amd-processor

I like to try out the new capability of perf c2c/mem for AMD arch (in detai: https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-6.1-Perf)

My environment is
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 6.1.0-060100-generic
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X (16) @ 3.600GHz

if I normally execute perf c2c record -a executable

I got a warning

```
WARNING: perf not found for kernel 6.1.0-060100

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-6.1.0-060100-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-6.1.0-060100-generic

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-generic
```

But I cannot install them

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-6.1.0-060100-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-6.1.0-060100-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-tools-6.1.0-060100-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-tools-6.1.0-060100-generic'
```

Anyone has idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

`sudo apt install linux-image-oem-22.04c linux-tools-oem-22.04c`

Reboot into that v6.1 kernel.

---

#### Additional

If you'd like to list all the versions of perf available, type `sudo apt install linux-tools-` and press **Tab** twice to autocomplete, and `bash-completion` will list out the several hundred available packages.

This solution works right now for v6.1 because Ubuntu has a v6.1 OEM kernel (provided for later hardware compatibility for OEMs).

You're lucky there's another v6.1 kernel and tools in the repo for the OEM kernel and its related packages.

You're currently using [Canonical kernel team's mainline package](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) `linux-image-6.1.0-060100-generic`, but they do not do builds of the other stuff like `linux-tools` or the debuginfo.

So if you were using something else, like the very latest v6.2.11, there is no pre-made `linux-tools` for that kernel version. You'd have to compile perf [from the kernel's `tools/perf` directory](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/tools/perf) or whatever other source directory you got your kernel from.

Comment: I installed inux-tools-6.1.0-1008-oem and linux-oem-22.04c by apt install but still I get the same result.

Comment: WARNING: perf not found for kernel 6.1.0-060100

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-6.1.0-060100-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-6.1.0-060100-generic

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-generi

Comment: `sudo apt install linux-image-oem-22.04c linux-tools-oem-22.04c` works fine for me. I slightly rewrote the answer. Try removing the existing mainline kernel you're currently using to get it completely out of the way.